# Google sheets binning and group by (custom time interval)

Tags: google-sheets, group-by, google-sheets-formula, binning

I wish to count events that occurred within a custom time interval : it could be within 24h, or within a week or 2-months span.

I am using google sheets: I can create a pivot table and group by month, however I'd like to explore insights using custom intervals (I'm looking for pattern in epilepsy).

As final result, I wanna have a table that, for each day, it is reported the number of frequencies within that interval.

Particularly, I wanna focus on the interval of 24h to count the number of events of epilepsy (known as cluster seizures).

And then, on custom days intervals to explore periodicity or trends - like each 48 hours, or each 15 or 30 days.

See a mockup of Google Sheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tCxYV5mUcq6vKm8-fL-0HUAOjcB9fipLCqPD2Znv-X0/edit#gid=1372548551

---

I tried this attempts:

1. find out how many events occurred in the last 30 days prior to the reported date:

```
= IFERROR(
  QUERY(                                                
     A:E,                                             
     "SELECT COUNT(A)                                   
      WHERE 
        A IS NOT NULL AND 
        E = FALSE AND 
        A >= date '" & 
          TEXT(
            A2-30,                                    
            "yyyy-MM-dd"                                
          ) &"' AND
        A <= date '" & 
          TEXT(
            A2,                                    
            "yyyy-MM-dd"                                
          ) &"'

    LABEL COUNT(A) '' "), "N/A")
```

Then, dragging the cell, I get the column "# events in the prior 30 days".

It works but seems a bit messy - especially for updating the intervals.

2. I tried this other approach:

```
=query(B:E, "select B, count(E), -1+count(E) where E = FALSE group by B label B 'Date with Clusters', count(E) 'Cluster seizures '")
```

That produces the last table.

I like this approach better, but here I am just grouping by the same date, without possibility to have a custom interval.

As an example, I will have that two events will be counted within the same day, not withing the same 24h interval.

Could you tell a better approach to handle datetime differences, so to create binning and group by with custom intervals ?

Below an example:
on the left table, data in input; on the middle column, result of first approach; on the right table, results of second approach.

[image]

Comment: @player0 I saw you answered to another question I posted, and I saw the google sheet example I posted here has a new sheet - might it be you, the author ? Unfortunately the new sheet reports the results of a possible solution, but not formulas to achieve it (may be due to copy paste of values). Would you mind to give it a look ? Thank you for sharing your expertise!

Comment: no, I'm not the author of that sheet, but I can show you some examples which may be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given the table:

[image]

in order to group stuff with QUERY we need to "fix" the A column in order to get a custom period. lets say we need to group events every 3 weeks (21 days). we take the lowest and highest date and create a sequence with all the dates in between.

```
=INDEX(ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A))))
```

then we use running total on it to get every date which is 21 days apart from the previous/next one. we could use simple SEQUENCE (for min>max) to create this array but with SEQUENCE we cant go "back in time" (for max>min) so we use MMULT and negative number

therefore, to start from a frame of the first date and create 3 weeks group by windows (eg. min>max) we use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({MIN(A2:A); MIN(A2:A)+MMULT(TRANSPOSE((
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))<=TRANSPOSE(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))*21); SiGN(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))})
```

and to get a reverse of it and start from frame of end date and create 3 weeks windows backwards (eg. max>min) we use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({MAX(A2:A); MAX(A2:A)+MMULT(TRANSPOSE((
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))<=TRANSPOSE(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))*-21); SiGN(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))})
```

[image]

at this stage, we can start fixing the A column via VLOOKUP and 4th argument set to `1` - approximate mode (instead of `0` - exact match mode) so forward in time will be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; SORT({MIN(A2:A); MIN(A2:A)+MMULT(TRANSPOSE((
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))<=TRANSPOSE(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))*21); SIGN(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))}); 1; 1)))
```

and backward in time shall be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; SORT({MAX(A2:A); MAX(A2:A)+MMULT(TRANSPOSE((
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))<=TRANSPOSE(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))*-21); SIGN(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))}); 1; 1)))
```

[image]

and now we just create a virtual array `{}` and pair fixed column A with column C and input it as range into QUERY

> side note:
>
> to put columns next to each other in english spreadsheets we use `,`
>
> to put columns next to each other in non-english spreadsheets we use `\`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; SORT({MIN(A2:A); MIN(A2:A)+MMULT(TRANSPOSE((
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))<=TRANSPOSE(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))*21); SIGN(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))}); 1; 1))\ C2:C}; 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col2 = FALSE 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

and backwards in time:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; SORT({MAX(A2:A); MAX(A2:A)+MMULT(TRANSPOSE((
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))<=TRANSPOSE(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))*-21); SIGN(
 ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(A2:A)&":"&MAX(A2:A)))))}); 1; 1))\ C2:C}; 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col2 = FALSE 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10OZD__K-zr8PX1fMlxK0WeOulPwqrJ6A5grBQ5xxwGw/edit#gid=893544029)

Comment: wOw. @Player0 you master GSheet. Thank you for dedicating time to elaborate some techniques to address my question. I was expecting use of `QUERY` more or less following the approach I tried ( like, ```TEXT(
            A2-21,                                    
            "yyyy-MM-dd"                                
          )```.  But you 've shown me a new approach  to elaborate custom intervals: I ll study it to better understand why you chose to use matrix multiplication. I understood the array must first be "expanded" with missing dates. Thanks again for dedicating time to teach!